# How can I keep a Xamarin label on screen with data bound to a Carosell Item

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have a

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{x:Static vm:MainPageViewModel.MyItems}">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding ID}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Progress}"/>
...
```

I would like the `<Label Text="{Binding Progress}"/>` not to scroll off screen, but to stay fixed (at the top) and update as the user swipes through the CarouselView items. If I move the label outside of the CarouselView, it won't be data bound.

How can I keep the label fixed onscreen, but bound to the curren CarouselView item? (Do I need to do this via code behind?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this easily by binding the text property of the `Label` to the property in your `ViewModel` which will also do binding to the `CurrentItem` property of `CarouselView`.

Can you try something like this:

```
<Label Text="{x:Static vm:MainPageViewModel.MyCurrentItem.Progress}"/>

<CarouselView CurrentItem="{x:Static vm:MainPageViewModel.MyCurrentItem}"
              ItemsSource="{x:Static vm:MainPageViewModel.MyItems}"

              ... other code
                  >
        ... other code
</CarouselView>
```

and in your `ViewModel` create a new bindable property of the same type as your MyItems list items are.

I have updated my GitHub repo with the example of this kind of behaviour:

You can find GitHub repo [**here**](https://github.com/almirvuk/Theatrum/tree/master/Theatrum.Mobile/Theatrum.Mobile).

and particular view [**here**](https://github.com/almirvuk/Theatrum/blob/master/Theatrum.Mobile/Theatrum.Mobile/Views/CarouselDemoPage.xaml).

And here is a GIF of a running demo:

[image]

`Label` is above the `CarouselView`, and when you swipe and change the selected item, the value of label is changing according to the change of `CarouselView`.

Hope this was helpful for you, wishing you lots of luck with coding!

Comment: Such a complete, comprehensive answer. Thank you!